# Instagram MIN_TIMESTAMP not returning all images it should

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, timestamp, instagram

I'm developing an iOS app and my idea is to display all Instagram images after a certain timestamp. I use [HSInstagram](https://github.com/hsandhu/HSInstagram) to handle the API response and put all the images in a UIScrolView.

In order to do so, I do a request to the following path: `users/%@/media/recent/?acces_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&min_timestamp=1350000000`. But the response I get is just a limited number of images, which aren't all the images after my timestamp.

I thought it was due to the limit that instagram puts on 20 images every request and thus I also tried to do the request to `users/%@/media/recent/?acces_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&min_timestamp=1350000000&count=-1` to avoid the limit. But in this case, the images didn't even load.

I'd appreciate any contribution. Thanks for your time!

Comment: If you don't know the answer to this question, but you know how to only load a specific amount of pictures such as 50. I've tried several times, by requesting tio the path: `users/%@/media/recent/?acces_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&count=50` but it doesn't work

Comment: If the response is paginated, send a request to the URL in the `pagination` part of the response

Comment: I think I'm not seeing your point. Would you mind explaining it in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [HSInstagram](https://github.com/hsandhu/HSInstagram) code was not prepared to implement the feature I wanted to implement, I foud an alternative called [GrabKit](https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit) in which you can also import your Facebook and Picasa images among others although you can disable them if you want to.

I hope this library can help you if you want to build an application that supports Instagram pictures the same way the app I'm building does. I really recommend it if you want to save thousands of lines of code as well as many hours dealing with APIs.